# Move Grid with Element Children

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i have this code as follows

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="one" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="49.667,15,15,15">
        <Grid x:Name="container1" Background="Red" Margin="10"/>
        <TextBlock Text="1"  FontSize="65" Margin="228,10,260,27"/>
    </Grid>

    <Button Content="mov" x:Name="first0" Click="first_Click" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13.333,27.833,0,0" Width="29.334" Background="Black" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Grid x:Name="due" Grid.Row="1" Background="black" Margin="49.667,15,15,15">
        <Grid x:Name="container2"  Margin="12,12,8,8" Background="#FF618F36"/>
        <TextBlock Text="2"  FontSize="65" Margin="228,10,198,27"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and the code behind:

```
private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (child != null && child is T)
            return (T)child;
        else
        {
            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void first_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var first = FindVisualChild<Grid>(one);
    var second = FindVisualChild<Grid>(due);
    one.Children.Remove(first);
    due.Children.Remove(second);
    one.Children.Add(second);
    due.Children.Add(first);
}
```

With this code i can move the "containers" in the Grid "one,due" but when i move the textblock disappear then i won't that ,because in future these grids will include others Grid,TextBox,textblock etc so kindly i ask you if there is a way to allow to move the containers including the childrens(textbox,textblock etc.)

Thank you in advance for the attention.

Sincerely

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but messing with the Visual Tree like that is probably not the right way to do it. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @HighCore I just want move the Grids(container1 and container2) between the Grid(one and due) with all Child element that  contains, in this case i just put inside the Grids(container1 and container2) one TextBlock but in real those contains more Element so with my code i can move the containers but when i move the TextBlock situated inside disappear.Hope you got the point.Thank you

Comment: that's not what I asked. My question is really what do you want to do this for? in WPF you don't grab pieces of the Visual Tree and move them around, without a `good` reason, What soft of UI or effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As I can see TextBlocks are not in your containers. When you remove container and add to another grid, it actually is added after TextBlock so containers are overlapping TextBlocks.

Comment: From reading your previous questions I understand that you're trying to perform a drag and drop operation between 2 or more sets of items-based UIs. Is this correct? if so, you need an `ItemsControl`, and probably use Gong's WPF DragDrop.

Comment: @HighCore I am sorry to misunderstand you ,i believe i wrong the code because the TextBlock should be inside the Grid.Anyway i have to develop a project that contain a program travel tour divided in days so the user can split/move days between them ..example : Day 1 can be moved to Day 5 , in the code i posted there are just 2 days

Comment: @JayJay you definitely need an `ItemsControl`. And the Gong framework probably suits your needs too. Create a proper DataModel and a couple of ObservableCollections and then manage your `data` (not the UI), and let the UI manage itself via DataBinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mark is right. The `TextBlock`s lie *on top of* your container grids, not inside them, which is why they don't move. Change your XAML to this, and it will work the way you expect:

```
...
<Grid x:Name="one" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="49.667,15,15,15">
    <Grid x:Name="container1" Background="Red" Margin="10">
        <TextBlock Text="1"  FontSize="65" Margin="228,10,260,27"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

<Button ...

<Grid x:Name="due" Grid.Row="1" Background="black" Margin="49.667,15,15,15">
    <Grid x:Name="container2"  Margin="12,12,8,8" Background="#FF618F36">
        <TextBlock Text="2"  FontSize="65" Margin="228,10,198,27"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
...
```